# Error while installing Easy-RSA as part of installing OpenVPN

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I am attempting to install OpenVPN on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04 by following [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html) in the documentation.  During the "Public Key Infrastructure Setup" section I get an error from the "clean-all" script and the "build-ca" script.

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
source vars
./clean-all
./build-ca
```

The error is:

```
Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")
Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.
```

The problem is that I have done so.  MANY times.  This is a new clean install of the OS.  I installed the OS then started the instructions to install and setup OpenVPN.  Then this happened.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I has this issue before, but I don't remember exactly how I fixed it. Did you try running `sudo source ./vars`?

Answer (score -1):

```
> This is how I solve the problem ... bob@ns1:~$ sudo chown bob:bob   
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/ bob@ns1:~$ cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/   
> bob@ns1:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa$ ls -la bob@ns1:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa$  
> source vars NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on 
> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/                                                
> keys bob@ns1:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa$ ./clean-all   
> bob@ns1:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa$ ./build-ca Generating a 2048 bit RSA   
> private key
```

Comment: Please clarify your answer